# Hyper Tetrahedron in terms of inequalities

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

The command Tetrahedron[] seems to work fine for the 3-d case. But how can we get hyper-tetrahedron for 4-d case in terms of inequality? Take for example the points:

```
P[0]={0,0,0,0};
P[1]={1,0,0,0};
P[2]={0,1,0,0};
P[3]={0,0,1,0};
P[4]={0,0,0,1};
```

The hyper-tetrahedron formed by these 5 points can be found out manually to be `x1>0 && x2>0 && x3>0 && x4>0 && x1+x2+x3+x4<1`. But how can we get it easily for any set of 5 points in 4-d using Mathematica?

Comment: Wouldn’t this be the same question you asked before in terms of `ConvexHull`? Does the solution you received there not work here?

Comment: Note what you have here isn't a regular tetrahedron such as that returned by `Tetrahedron[]`. You're actually showing a `Simplex[3]`. If you want a regular one see here for the coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell

Comment: @MarcoB. No, it won't work for the 4-d cases

Comment: I was searching through the Wolfram library. Do you think Simplex[] will work for finding Hyper-tetrahedron? @MarcoB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `Simplex` instead:

```
Refine[RegionMember[Simplex[P /@ Range[0,4]], {x,y,z,w}], {x,y,z,w} ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && w >= 0 && w+x+y+z <= 1
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to get rid of this (x|y|z|w) ∈ Reals part from the answer?

Comment: @SumitBanik See my edit.